# Plastic shower pan about to crack. Any preventive measures to take before it is too late?

Tags: repair, shower, leak, plastic

Recently our shower pan started to make really loud, cracking sounds when we step on it. I feel that it will crack, if we don't take any action. The paint has already come off slightly in the places where I suspect it would crack first.

**Any ideas how to fix it or at least extend shower pans lifespan so that more expensive repair could be avoided?**

See pictures with annotations.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening to one of my tubs.  I discovered that the tub is sitting on a block of styrofoam, and apparently rats chewed holes in it and created unsupported areas that flex when stepped on.  I'm going to have to replace the whole thing sooner or later, but I temporarily fixed it by epoxying fiberglass patches over the weakened areas.

Update: the patches held up for two years before I sprung for a new tub.

Comment: Aside from an issue of rats, expoxy/fiberglass is the proper fix for this.  And if done properly will not require replacement of the unit (though matching it visually may be difficult).

Comment: @ssaltman and Kevin  Another solution seems to be to replace the styrofoam (or whatever foundation is below the shower pan). What do you think about this? But to be honest I don't see an elegant way to access it without removing the shower pan itself.

Comment: @Jonny In my case, I could probably saw off the outside wall of the tub to replace the foam.  It's not structural; there are wooden supports between the rim of the basin and the floor.  I'd have to reattach the front with a molding strip or something to make it look halfway decent.  I've already drilled a small hole in it to insert an inspection camera and plugged it with a chrome metal cap meant for electrical junction boxes.